# Getting popup inside of fixed-width container to auto-size properly

Tags: css

I have a bunch of "help" links that have content in them that appears on mouseover.  The links are all 15x15px and I want the nested popup to auto-size itself, but am having issues getting it to work.  It's easy to make this work if I pull the popups outside of their container, but then they're just restricted to the width of the next parent container...

http://jsfiddle.net/NsGaN/

```
<a href="#">
    <div>this text should not wrap</div>
</a>
<a href="#">
    <div class="div2">this text should wrap once the div reaches 300 pixels wide, but not before that</div>
</a>

a {
    display     : block;
    width       : 20px;
    position    : relative;
}

div {
    position    : absolute;
    border      : 1px solid #000;
    max-width   : 300px;
    padding     : 10px;
    top         : 10px;
    left        : 10px;
}

.div2 {
    top : 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: http://jsfiddle.net/NsGaN/4/

You need to decide why you want to constrict the links to 20px (15x15) when you also don't want text to wrap, these two points are kinda self-exclusive

Comment: No they're not.  The content is absolutely positioned relative to the link, meaning it's pulled out of the document flow.  The link itself is an image which is a certain size.  Even if I remove the constraint on the image, I still run into the issue that if ANY parent container is a fixed-width smaller than 300px, the popup gets constrained.

Comment: I was talking about restricting the the links, not the pop-ups.

Comment: I know, I'm saying it's irrelevant.  Take the following: `<div style="width:100px;"><a><div class="popup"></a></div>` -- even if the link size isn't restricted, the popup is now still restricted to 100px wide.

Answer (score 0):

if you change your css to this:

```
a {
  width:20px;
  position:relative;
}

div {
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding:10px;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
  float:left;
  max-width:300px;
}
```

It'll be what your looking for.

Comment: won't work -- The divs need to be absolutely positioned relative to the A